# No scrollbar after resize

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

I am fairly new to C#.  I am using a WPF Datagrid, not a DataGridView.  I populate the data grid just fine.

The work station I work on has a 4:3 1280x1024 screen.  My Managers screen is 16:9 1920x1080.  So I have a need to re-size the datagrid when my manager re-sizes the window on his computer.
When the window is re-sized, I have to programmatically re-size the datagrid, because, even after setting the datagrids width and height to "auto", the grid does not re-size when the window is re-sized.  As soon as I start re-sizing the window, the datagrid loses the horizontal scrollbar.

After doing some digging, I found out that all the columns get frozen when I re-size the datagrid.  The WPF datagrid has a read only property of "isFrozen", I have not seen any way to unfreeze the columns.  Is there a way to unfreeze columns of a datagrid?

Comment: why do you need to programatically reszie the datagrid?  you can't just have it fill the available space like normal?

Comment: I had set the width and height to auto, but when I resize the window, the grid did not resize, I have to do it manually.